# Why I don't get a connection? Java.. SQL Server Express Edition (server)

Tags: java, sql-server

Where do I have a bug? A mistake? Why can't I connect? My code,

```
    package conexiones;
    import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Connection;

    public class miconexion {
        static String db = "futbol";
        static String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName="+db+";";

        //(local)\SQLEXPRESS
        //String conn;
        public Connection conn;

        public miconexion() {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url);
                System.out.println("conexion exitosa");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.out.println("no conectado");
            }
        }

        public Connection getConnection()
        {
            return conn;
        }

        public void desconectar()
        {
            conn=null;
        }

        public static void main(String [] ar )
        {
            miconexion con = new miconexion();
            con.getConnection();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Post your exception stacktrace please.

Comment: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: No se pudo realizar la conexión TCP/IP al host (local), puerto 1433. Error: "null. Verifique las propiedades de conexión, compruebe que hay una instancia de SQL Server ejecutándose en el host y aceptando las conexiones TCP/IP en el puerto y compruebe que no hay ningún firewall bloqueando las conexiones TCP en el puerto."

Comment: Translation : `Could not connect TCP / IP host (local) port 1433. Error: "null. Check your connection properties, check for an instance of SQL Server running on the host and accepting TCP / IP connections on port and check that there is no firewall blocking connections on port TCP`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to enable basic authentication.  By default MS SQL Server only accepts trusted (aka Windows login) connections.  You'll also need to create a user and specify the username and password in the connection string.

Comment: i have seen in the web, people get connect without a username and a password,  now i get that mistake you are telling, it is..the next"error of beginning of session"

Comment: If they're connecting without a username and password then it's likely using trusted authentication.  I think there may be a way to ask the MS JDBC drivers to do it but it's not automatic.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server Express Edition, try

```
static String url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName="+db+";";
```

Answer (score 1):

By default MS SQL Server (and probably Express) is not enabled for TCP (JDBC) connections.  You need to go into the server configuration and [enable TCP](http://www.webxpert.ro/andrei/2009/05/31/enable-tcpip-on-sql-server-2005-express-edition/).

Answer (score 0):

If you have liberty to choose on Db driver. Go for JTDS opensource driver for SQL Server.

Connection String example..

```
jdbc:jtds:<server_type>://<server>[:<port>][/<database>][;<property>=<value>[;...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

My code can help you, you can connect over 127.0.0.1 on your machine.

[sqlserver express connection over servername\instancename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22847054/sqlserver-express-connection-over-servername-instancename)

also you should enable tcp/ip in sql configuration, and also enable for ip ( 127.0.0.1)